# Post Yammer activity to a particular group

Tags: yammer

I'm using the Yammer Open Graph API, and have defined custom actions for it. Is there a way to only post this to a particular group?

This is my API request body:

```
{
"activity":{
"actor":{"name":"Saurav Sircar",
"email":"saurav.sirca@schneider-electric.com"},
"action":"test123:approve",
"object": {
 "url":"https://www.google.com",
 "type": "test123:demand",
 "title":"Lunch Meeting"
},
"message":"API test"
}
}
```

Where do I add the group ID info?

Answer (score 0):

You can't target activities to a specific group since the Activity Stream is a per-user feed only shown on the homepage. You can post messages to groups with the same Open Graph metadata that you have specified in the object element.